# Definition of natural numbers in ZF

Tags: set-theory

I'm going through Enderton's *Elements of Set Theory* and he's just defined a natural number as a set that belongs to any inductive set. The problem is that this statement seems to need the notion of proper class, since the class of all inductive sets is not a set.

Am I wrong here? If not, is there any set theoretic construction of the natural numbers that doesn't need proper classes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Abusing notation, $\in$ for proper classes isn't like $\in$ for sets: for $x$ a set and $Y=\{z\mid\phi(z)\}$ a proper class, $x\in Y$ doesn't literally make sense since $Y$ is not in the domain of discourse, instead it's notation for $\phi(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no use of classes here at all: the definition is simply $$Nat(a)\quad:=\quad \forall x(Ind(x)\rightarrow a\in x)$$ (where "$Ind(x)$" is an abbreviation for "$x$ is an inductive set"). The fact that the inductive sets form a class doesn't matter.

(Admittedly, the **intuitive idea** of "intersection of the class of inductive sets" makes reference to a proper class, but the point is that this can be subsumed by the power of the $\forall$-quantifier in first-order logic - namely its ability, indeed *duty*, to range over the whole universe.)